# can't compile simple plain text in Lyx (lyx_tmpbuf2)

Tags: lyx, miktex

I have recently installed a portable Lyx 2.0.8 in Win7. I already run Miktex update and reconfigure Lyx. However, I just write a few lines on Lyx (plain text, no more) and cannot compile it on pdf.

the error message states: "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.Hp9044/lyx_tmpbuf2/1.pdf file does not exist"
"error in the preliminary view of the file in the format:pdf2".

Does anybody know how to fix it, please?

Comment: I don't see this problem on Ubuntu. You could try setting the temporary directory path in Tools > Preferences > PATHs.

Comment: sorry, it didn't work. I changed the working path (first gap) to the directory that the error points and still drops the same error. another error line that appears in the message is "pdflatex  "1.tex" > nul". As you might guess, 1.lyx is the name of my file.

Comment: I have no idea how to diagnose this on Windows. Hopefully someone else comes along. You might consider installing LyX 2.1.4. There are of course risks to upgrading, but it doesn't seem like you have much to lose since you can't currently compile.

Comment: The only solution I could guess (and it works) is to download the Lyx portable version, which comes with Miktex included.

Comment: How are you compiling? With the eyes button? You might consider using SumatraPDF as your viewer. I have seen it solve errors like this one for Windows users.

Comment: Yes, I'm using eyes button. I will try SumatraPDF just in case. For the moment portable version lets me work. Thanks!